# CollectionView cells initially appearing too small, then jumping to correct size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

## Background

I'm creating a calendar in my iOS app that is built around a `UICollectionView`. There is a section for each month, then a cell for each day. My calendar view is defined in an `xib`, then loaded into my custom class using the following code inside the `init` method:

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CalendarView", owner: self, options: nil)
addSubview(contentView)

contentView.frame = self.bounds
contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

My overridden layout subviews method looks like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    layout.invalidateLayout() //My subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
}
```

I'm sizing the cells so that there are always 7 on a row using the following method in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (collectionView.bounds.width - 1) / 7.0
    return CGSize(width: width, height: min(width, 48))
}
```

The cells are also defined in a separate `xib` file.

---

## The Problem

When the containing view controller loads, the cells are all too small, then after about 1 second they snap to the correct size. This happens on the first load only, the widths are correct after rotation or after resizing the app in iPad multitasking mode.

---

## What I've Tried

None of the following things have worked.

- Calling `layoutSubviews()` after configuring my cell
- Changing the `UICollectionView` cell size in the xib file
- Setting the estimated item size property on my layout object

Comment: can you please try to set fixed height instead of min(width,48)?

Comment: Having the same trouble, moreover, with dynamic cell height scrolling behaves like crazy fox. Non-stop jumping.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the dynamic sizing cell, you should add the `estimatedItemSize` in the FlowLayout.

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {    
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: flowLayout.itemSize.width, height: flowLayout.itemSize.height)                                                     
}
```

Reference: Article about auto sizing cell attached [here](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2).

Comment: As stated in the question, I've already tried that with no success